# Returning a specific value from a function in common lisp?

Tags: function, common-lisp, sbcl

I wrote a function with clsql. All it does is read the entire table. First it opens the connection, reads, then closes.

```lisp
(defun select()
  (clsql:connect "new.db" :database-type :sqlite3)

  (clsql:print-query
   "select * from contacts"
   :titles '("id" "firstname" "email" "company" "firstline" "status"))
  (clsql:disconnect :database "new.db"))
```

With the `disconnect` expression last, I get `T` as the return value.

I want to get the value of `clsql:print-query` returned. However, the disconnection should go last because I need to make sure the connection closes.

I tried `block` and `return-with`, with no luck.

What is the best way to approach returning values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To really make sure that a thing runs when leaving a scope use `UNWIND-PROTECT`.

```
(unwind-protect (read-the-file stream)
  (print "closing")
  (close stream))
```

Examples:

Here we make sure that some code runs after a form.

```
CL-USER 41 > (unwind-protect (progn  ; protected form
                               (print "doing-something")
                               (values))
               (print "ensuring safety"))  ; this WILL run

"doing-something" 
"ensuring safety"
```

Here we see what happens if there is an error in the protected form:

```
CL-USER 42 > (unwind-protect (progn
                               (error "foo")
                               (print "doing-something")
                               (values))
               (print "ensuring safety"))

Error: foo
  1 (abort) Return to top loop level 0.

Type :b for backtrace or :c <option number> to proceed.
Type :bug-form "<subject>" for a bug report template or :? for other options.

CL-USER 43 : 1 > :c 1                 ; ABORTING

"ensuring safety"
```

Above shows that the PRINT call was running when leaving the scope.

If you only want to return the first forms value, one can use PROG1, which does not protect from errors.

```
CL-USER 44 > (prog1
                 (sin 3)
               (print "hello"))

"hello" 
0.14112
```

Above might be something like (but with some temp1 name which can not be inconflict with user code):

```
(let ((temp1 (sin 3)))
  (print "hello")
  temp1)
```

**Your example with UNWIND-PROTECT**

```
(defun select()
  (clsql:connect "new.db" :database-type :sqlite3)
  (unwind-protect
      (clsql:print-query
       "select * from contacts"
       :titles '("id" "firstname" "email" "company" "firstline" "status"))
    (clsql:disconnect :database "new.db")))
```

Comment: What is unwind-protect actually doing in the background?

Comment: @Vinn it executes the protected form. It then runs the clean-up form. If the protected form gets aborted due to an error, then the clean-up form is also run. For example if from the databases can't be read due to an connection error, the disconnect call is still run. unwind-protect is a standard special-operator in Common Lisp. Something like WITH-OPEN-FILE is also built upon it.

Comment: Understood. Very valuable. But why is the protected form returned when it is not the "last form" which usually gets returned?

Comment: Because its value is saved and then returned.

Comment: Common lisp would be 2x more difficult to pick up without helpful people like you. Thank you Rainer.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want `clsql:with-database` which connects to the DB and wraps your queries in a `unwind-protect` for you, ensuring the DB connection is closed no matter what.

https://clsql.kpe.io/manual/with-database.html

```
(clsql:with-database (db '("new.db") :database-type :sqlite3
                      :make-default nil)
  (clsql:database-name db))
```